# How to migrate Firebase Cloud Functions Legacy to 11.0.1

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I currently use `8.13.0` of `firebase-admin` and `3.7.0` of `firebase-functions` but upon seeing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node) it seems the firebase-admin already includes firebase-functions. I tried to deploy my code numerous time with `11.0.1`, the function was created and deployed but I am getting an error saying that Failed to load due to error in user code. I tried to update the functions but ultimately failed.

This is what I tried

```
'use-strict'

const admin = require("firebase-admin/app");
const functions = require('firebase-admin/functions');
const messaging = require('firebase-admin/messaging');


admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.applicationDefault()
});




// Customize Cloud Functions behavior using RuntimeOptions
// Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/function_configuration.runtimeoptions
const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '1GB'
};


/*
 * 'onCreate' triggered when a document is created.
 * 'onUpdate' triggered when a document is updated.
 * 'onDelete' triggered when a document is deleted.
 * 'onWrite' works like 'addValueEventListener' or 'addSnapshotListener' in the client.
 * It will fire the function every time there the item was added, removed or update 
 *
 */

exports.announcement = functions.getFunctions().region('asia-northeast3').runWith(runtimeOpts).firestore.document("Announcement/{doc_id}").onCreate(async (added) => {

    const topicName = "Announcement";

    const title = added.data().title;
    const description = added.data().description;
    const bigImage = added.data().big_image;
    const link = added.data().link;
    const environment = added.data().environment;

    // This payload is migrated to V1, reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1
    // To modify the priority/urgency see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message
    const payload = {
        topic: topicName,
        data: {
            title: title,
            description: description,
            big_image: bigImage,
            link: link,
            environment: environment
        },
        android: {
            priority: 'normal'
        },
        apns: {
            headers: {
                'apns-priority': '5'
            }
        },
        webpush: {
            headers: {
                Urgency: 'low'
            }
        }
    };

    try {
        const val = await messaging.getMessaging().send(payload);
        console.log("Success!\n" + JSON.stringify(payload), val);
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to send notification.", error);
        return true;
    }

});
```

Error

```
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug
in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the 
error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs.
```

Working in 8.13.0

```
'use-strict'

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');


admin.initializeApp();



// Customize Cloud Functions behavior using RuntimeOptions
// Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/function_configuration.runtimeoptions
const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '1GB'
};


/*
 * 'onCreate' triggered when a document is created.
 * 'onUpdate' triggered when a document is updated.
 * 'onDelete' triggered when a document is deleted.
 * 'onWrite' works like 'addValueEventListener' or 'addSnapshotListener' in the client.
 * It will fire the function every time there the item was added, removed or update 
 *
 */

exports.announcement = functions.region('asia-northeast3').runWith(runtimeOpts).firestore.document("Announcement/{doc_id}").onCreate(async (added) => {

    const topicName = "Announcement";

    const title = added.data().title;
    const description = added.data().description;
    const bigImage = added.data().big_image;
    const link = added.data().link;
    const environment = added.data().environment;

    // This payload is migrated to V1, reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1
    // To modify the priority/urgency see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message
    const payload = {
        topic: topicName,
        data: {
            title: title,
            description: description,
            big_image: bigImage,
            link: link,
            environment: environment
        },
        android: {
            priority: 'normal'
        },
        apns: {
            headers: {
                'apns-priority': '5'
            }
        },
        webpush: {
            headers: {
                Urgency: 'low'
            }
        }
    };

    try {
        const val = await admin.messaging().send(payload);
        console.log("Success!\n" + JSON.stringify(payload), val);
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to send notification.", error);
        return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: It's more likely someone can help if you show what you tried for the upgrade already, and what error message you got.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the question is now updated, thanks

Comment: Your implementation for timeout and memory seems different than the one proposed in the [public documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) could you try updating this and let us know if it makes any change?

Comment: @Chris32 hmm, I don't see any difference? They are both object so you can make it a variable to avoid repetition.